# RSpec is displaying an Action View error but the page renders perfectly on local host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

The test I'm writing is checking to see if I can delete an assignment or not. I thought I'd check for the presence of the link itself first:

```
describe "Deleting an assignment" do
        before{ visit assignments_path }
        it{ should have_selector('th', text: "Band Member") }
    end
```

Now when I load the page itself it renders perfectly without any errors (haven't tried pushing to Heroku yet), but the testing environment returns:

```
Failures:

  1) Assignment pages Deleting an assignment 
     Failure/Error: before{ visit assignments_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

the code that's causing the error is in my assignment stub

```
<td><%= assignment.user.name + " " + assignment.user.surname%></td>
```

My assignments controller's index action is simply:

```
  def index
  @assignments = Assignment.all
  end
```

I can't see anything obvious so any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you have an assignment with no user. How are the assignments created?

Comment: My models are:

Users who have many Roles through assignments.
Roles have many Users through assignments.

Assignments have a user_id and a role_id.

I created the assignment in the test by using:
@assignment = Assignment.create(user_id: 1, role_id: 1)

Comment: is there a user with id 1 - check the id of the user that you've created.

Comment: I think so? 

Here's the code that executes before the test executes:

`before do
      @user = User.create(name: "Jim", surname: "User", email:"jim@jim.com",
      phone:"01224555555", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
      @roleFirst = Role.create(description: "Tester")
      @roleSecond = Role.create(description: "Role Two")
      @assignment = Assignment.create(user_id: 1, role_id: 1)
      sign_in(@user)
    end `

Comment: So presumably the ID of the user (seeing as it's the first one created for this test) would be 1?

Comment: The fact that the test fails suggests that it isn't. Why not print it to the console to check? In general assuming this sort of stuff is a surefire way to have brittle tests

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I mean I know how to access the console through rails -c and all but I'm not sure how to check what's going on in the test database as opposed to the one I'm using for development?

Comment: just add a couple of calls to puts in your spec code so see what it's doing. Or add some breakpoints (you'll need to install the debugger gem)

Comment: I've accessed it through rails c test but when I go to create a user it's assigning it the ID 31 not 1 so I guess that must be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the first instance of a user created in the test environment was 31 not 1. This was because I was creating a set of 30 users in another test suite but deleting the users afterwards (hence why user 1 didn't exist). I got around this by assigning the role using a call rather than hard coding what I thought was the ID.

```
@assignment = Assignment.create(user_id: @user.id, role_id: @roleSecond.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different databases for test and development? If you are, check that in your test database all of your assignments have a user.